# Why CardView clipping does not work on API Level below 21?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <View
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:background="#f22" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want remove extra vertical line outside of `CardView`. In fact I want have radiused vertical line.

In Android api 21 and higher everything is ok.

---

visual :

[image]

Comment: Try `android:clipChildren="true"` to `RelativeLayout` also.

Comment: @JeelVankhede not work

Comment: @JeelVankhede Can you put an example?

Answer (score 0):

i believe there is no need for that LinearLayout(parent of your card). so just remove it and make it really a card.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:background="#f22" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

try using `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` & `android:clipChildren="true"` too